# PHPMailer shows weird character

Tags: php

I develop a "forgot password" functions on my login page using PHPMailer.

The problem that I am facing is that when I click on the forgot password and enter the email, the page will redirect to student_email.php (which contain most of the PHPMailer code) and show a bunch of text which I believe should be related to the email process itself. See the photo below.

[image]

However, the recovery email is working, I can see the email and password on my email.

Any way to get rid of random string of text? Maybe just show the "Email Sent" dialog box is good for me.

Here is the code

1. LOGIN.PHP

```PHP
<?php
    session_start(); 
    include('include/header.php');
    include('admin/include/dbcon.php');
 ?>
 
 <!-- STUDENT LOGIN FORM SECTION START -->

<section class="LoginForm-bg-image navbar-bottom-space">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 my-col">
                    <div class="outerdiv">
                        <h2 class="Login-text">Student Login</h2>
                        <div class="InnerDiv">
                            <form method="post" action="">
                               <div class="form-group">
                                 <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                                 <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby= "emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" required="true">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                                  <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" required="true">
                                </div>
                                <center>
                                    <button name="submit2" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-login-form">Login</button>
                                    <p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Sforgotpass" class="forgot-para">Forgot Password?</p>
                                </center>
                            </form>
                        </div>    
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- STUDENT FORM SECTION END -->

<!-- FORGOT PASSWORD DIALOG START -->

<div class="modal fade" id="Sforgotpass" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title forgot-heading" id="exampleModalLabel">RESET PASSWORD</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
        <p class="forgot-heading2">Forgot your password?</p> 
        <p>Enter your email address and we will send you instructions on how to reset your password.</p>
        <form action="student_email.php" method="post">
           <div class="form-group col-md-10 input-forgot-div">
             <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby= "emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" required="true">
            </div>
            <center>
                <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-login-form">Send Email</button>
            </center>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- FORGOT PASSWORD DIALOG END -->



<?php 
    include('include/footer.php');
?>

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    history.pushState(null, "", location.href.split("?")[0]);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
  $var=$_GET['msg'];
  echo "<script>alert('$var')</script>";
}

  if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
    $value1 = $_POST["email"];
    $value2 = $_POST["password"];
    $data = mysqli_query($sql_con,"select *from students where stdemail = '$value1' AND password='$value2'");
    $datarow = mysqli_num_rows($data);
    if ($datarow > 0) {
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
      $value3 = $row['id'];
      $_SESSION['sid'] = $value3;
      echo "<script>window.location='/students/dashboard.php'</script>";
    }
    else{
      echo "<script>alert('Invalid information please try again')</script>";
     
    }
    
  }

 ?>
```

2.STUDENT_EMAIL.PHP

```PHP
<?php 
  include('admin/include/dbcon.php');
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $inpemail = $_POST['email'];
  $data = mysqli_query($sql_con,"select * from students where stdemail = '$inpemail'");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
  $email = $row['stdemail'];
  if($email != $inpemail){
    echo "<script>alert('Email does not exist')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location='studentlogin.php'</script>";
    return false;
  }
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
  
  //Enable SMTP debugging.
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
  //Set PHPMailer to use SMTP.
  $mail->isSMTP();
  //Set SMTP host name
  $mail->Host = "mail.XXXX.com";
  $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                    'ssl' => array(
                        'verify_peer' => false,
                        'verify_peer_name' => false,
                        'allow_self_signed' => true
                    )
                );
  //Set this to true if SMTP host requires authentication to send email
  $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
  //Provide username and password
  $mail->Username = "myemail";
  $mail->Password = "mypassword";
  //If SMTP requires TLS encryption then set it
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "false";
  $mail->Port = 587;
  //Set TCP port to connect to
  
  $mail->From = "xxx@xxx.com";
  $mail->FromName = "XXX Student Portal System";
  
  $mail->addAddress($row["stdemail"]);
  
  $mail->isHTML(true);
 
  $mail->Subject = "This mail is from XXX Portal System to show your password";
  $mail->Body = "<i>This is your password:</i>".$row["password"];
  $mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";
  if(!$mail->send())
  {
  
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<script>alert('Email Sent')</script>";
  }
  }
  
   ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `//Enable SMTP debugging.` – you want to _disable_ it then …

Comment: You guys are awesome, I am not  sure what keyword to search for. Thanks!!